# How to inconsistency between parseFloat("") and isNaN("")

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js, hash

I need to check if value `isNaN("") === true` but it returns false but `parseFloat("")` returns `NaN`.

Why I need this is because I am doing hash check with `JSON.stringify()` and knockout observable instead of numeric value returns a string numeric value.

E.g. Instead of `1.23` it returns `"1.23"`.

**Question**: How to parse string numeric values without getting `NaN` as result?

Comment: I'm confused about what exactly you want. Do you want to filter out `""`?

Comment: If you don't want to exit out, choose a fallback for when you aren't getting expected input e.g. `x = +str || 0;` (simple case because `0 || 0` gives `0`, though it's from the _RHS_)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to parse string numeric values without getting NaN as result?

Well...you can't, if the values can't be parsed as numeric values. But `"1.23"` **can** be parsed as a numeric value:

```
var num = parseFloat("1.23");
console.log(num); // 1.23
```

If you need to check if the result will be `NaN`, check *the result*:

```
isNaN(parseFloat(yourInput)) === true
```

...except there is exactly **zero** point in the `=== true` part of that, so:

```
isNaN(parseFloat(yourInput))
```

`parseFloat` and the default coercion to number used if you pass a string into `isNaN` follow different rules. In particular, `parseFloat` will stop parsing as of the first non-numeric, but `isNaN` [in effect] uses the `Number` function, which will fail if there are non-numeric characters. So if you need to rely on getting a result from `parseFloat` that is not `NaN`, you have to call `parseFloat` and pass its result into `isNaN`.

Here's an example: `"1.23aaa"` Let's see what we see there:

```
console.log(parseFloat("1.23aaa"));        // 1.23
console.log(isNaN("1.23aaa"));             // true!!
console.log(isNaN(parseFloat("1.23aaa"))); // false
```

`parseFloat` stops trying as of the first `a`, but the default coercion from string to number you're invoking by passing a string into `isNaN` *doesn't*.

Comment: Good point. I was thinking just checking value with `isNaN` but in this way when I am actually checking the `parseFloat` result solves the problem.

Comment: @skmasq: Just for completeness: The alternative is to keep using `isNaN(string)` and then use `Number(string)` to parse it. That's another way to use the same rules in both cases.